# Advantages of using UniqueIdentifier datatype over nvarchar(32) containing a GUID?

Tags: c#, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I want to know what are the advantages of a `UniqueIdentifier` datatype in SQL Server

**Over** `nvarchar(32)` datatype which contains a GUID **String** (being sent from C#).

Comment: @marc_s , I wanted nvarchar since i thought : "I dont need all these 32 chars , I think 8 guid CHARS are sufficient to be unique..." - so i Cut 8 chars from the 32 chars guid. , But probably it wont be as unique...

Comment: A guid (uniqueidentifier) is not stored as text; you are just seeing that in your tools (the same as dates are not text)

Comment: You really need to reed [Performance Considerations of Datatypes](http://sqlfool.com/2009/05/performance-considerations-of-data-types/) by Michelle Ufford - she clearly explains **WHY** it's of utmost importance to pick the **right** (most suitable) datatype for your data columns

Comment: @marc_s 8 bytes is 8*1 chars... but guid has 32 chars so...how ?

Comment: @marc_s Im not using nvarchar(max) for everything - I just thought I didnt need that long guid , and Thought I can use a part of it.:)

Comment: @marc_s 16 byte= 16*8 bits = 128 bit.  divided by 32 (places ) = 4 . so 2^5-1 which is that max value for each place ?

Comment: @marc_s Ive just asked about how 16 bit can be represented as 32 chars in the guid ( i was talking about the GUID = 16 byte)

Comment: Each single byte of a GUID is represented by **two** hexadecimal characters (0-9,A-F); one byte can range from 0 to 255 - those values are represented in a string form as `00` through `FF` --> **two** characters are needed for representing a single (binary) byte

Comment: See [Hexadecimal on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

Comment: @marc_s , can you tell me where im wrong in http://i.stack.imgur.com/kuLXp.jpg ?

Comment: Though this is not answer to your question, but just wannted to share my experience you should  check your db if supports supports Guid operations. I was bitten by SQL Server 2000 when it refused to execute Count(MyGuid_Column) :)

Comment: GUID: 16 byte = 128 bit is correct; each character represents 4 bits (thus values 0-15, as `0`-`9` and `A`-`F`), thus 2^4 values. So to represent 128 bits, you need 32 characters (32*4 = 128)

Comment: @marc_s As always , Thank you for your help and attention.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the server's point of view:

- I'd expect a `Guid` field to be stored more efficiently - it only needs 16 bytes, instead of 32 or potentially 64+ depending on exactly how the nvarchar is stored
- It *can* be treated as opaque binary data by the server - *no* intelligence is required when making comparisons, for example. No cultural or case sensitivity. It's fundamentally *not* textual data, so doesn't have all the issues and complexities associated with text.
- The server *could* decide to use the known structure of a Guid to index more efficiently. For example, if some bits are more likely to be randomly distributed than others, those could be used for indexing.

From a programmer's point of view:

- It makes a clearer statement about the expected data.
- You don't need any validation, and you'll never have any concerns about invalid data - they're just GUIDs.

I'm a big fan of keeping data in whatever form is closest to the logical meaning of the data. For example, if you're going to store date and time data, it makes life *much* simpler for comparisons etc if you've got a date/time value rather than a string. Conversions to and from string (or any other representation, but it's usually string) should only be performed where *necessary*.

Comment: Of course Jon Skeet would be the one to answer my question... and 11 years ago. I am curious if you can update it. I see you said you "expect" it to be more efficient, and "it can" be treated as opaque, and it "could" be more efficient, perhaps because not all these potentialities were in place (yet?). I don't seem to find clear answers elsewhere. The only thing I did find stated the GUID is stored in 16 bytes as it is HEX. (Was "8 bytes" a typo?). Can you confirm if any of these potentialities have been implemented, or if there have been any advancements? Thanks in advance for your insights!

Comment: @Hawkeye: Yes, I meant 16 bytes. But no, I'm not in a position to test this at all. I haven't used SQL Server for years. If this is still of interest to you, I assume you're in a much better position to test it than I am.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you anyway! Hmm, maybe I'll do that and update here when I have chance. I was able to make the case to switch to use `UniqueIdentifier` with your answer already, so it's not of urgent importance, but I may try to test it out. Thanks again!